# How to get youtube iframe videos to resize properly when viewed on iOS?

Tags: iphone, css, video, browser, mobile-safari

I'm running a response theme and the videos show up fine when viewed on a normal browser, but when they are viewed on a mobile device (I'm using an iPhone) they aren't resizing correctly.

Instead of staying within the content area, the videos overflow into the sidebar.

These videos are iframe Youtube video embeds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added iframe {max-width:100%;} and it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Resizing videos is difficult. Consider using this jQuery plugin: [fitvids](http://fitvidsjs.com/).

Comment: Hmmm, it's working for other people as is without that plug in. Check this site out http://www.everchangingmedia.com/category/videos/

Comment: I added iframe {max-width:100%;} and it seems to work. I'd appreciate if someone could check on their mobile phone and see if they are viewing correctly on your end? Thanks!

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable here, but you should go ahead and add it as an answer rather than a comment. You can even mark it as the accepted answer. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here, and learning how everything works. Actually I just figured out why I didn't answer my question, I can't do that until 8 hours have passed..

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my mobile theme to hide elements that could be problematic on mobile devices:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.mobilehide {
    visibility: collapse;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

I hope that this is useful to you.

Comment: You are actually going for a lazy solution that is to hide elements. You should definitely try a fix.